# Using $.when() and .done() with jQuery's $.each

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page where I create a customer (company) and its contacts in two async calls to the database. Contacts should be saved after the Customer because it needs a Customer Id which is included in the server response. Also, after all is done, there is a redirect to the appropriate new Customer page.

As is, the redirect occurs even before any contact is saved. I tried using jQuery's `$.when()` and `.done()`, but it doesn't work possibly because there is a disconnect between `.when()` and the callbacks. How can I make it work in this situation?

```
function saveAll() {
    createCustomer();
    createContacts();
    var url = "<newCustomerDetailPage>";    // redirect when all is done
    window.location = url;
}


function callback(result) {
    if (result) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}


function errorHandler(error) {
    // do something
}


function createCustomer() {       // Create 1 new customer
    // prep fields
    var client = new toolkit.Client();
    client.create(<fields>, callback, errorHandler);
}


function createContacts() {       // Create 1 or more new contacts
    $('.row').each(function() {
        // prep fields
        createContact(fields);
    }
}


function createContact(fields) {      // Create 1 new contact
    var client = new toolkit.Client();
    client.create(<fields>, callback, errorHandler);
}


function handleResult(result, callback, errorHandler) {
    if (blah...)
        callback(result)
    else
        errorHandler(error)
}
```

**toolkit.Client:**

```
toolkit.Client = function(){}

toolkit.Client.prototype.create = function(fields, callback, errorHandler) {
    // async call to database 
    function(result){        // handle server response
        handleResult(result, callback, errorHandler);
    }
}
```

Note that `client.create` can only save one record at a time.

**Tried already:**

```
var actions = [];

function createContacts() {       // Create 1 or more new contacts
    $('.row').each(function() {
        // prep fields
        actions.push(function(){createContact(fields);});
    }
}

function saveAll() {
    createCustomer();
    createContacts();
    $.when.apply($,actions).done(function(){
        var url = "<newCustomerDetailPage>";    // redirect when all is done
        window.location = url;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wait the end of the each loop using [`promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) :

```
var actions = [];

function createContacts(callback) {       // Create 1 or more new contacts
    $('.row').each(function() {
        // prep fields
        actions.push(function(){createContact(fields);});
    }.promise().done(callback);
}

function saveAll() {
    createCustomer();
    createContacts(function(){
        $.when.apply($,actions).done(function(){
            var url = "<newCustomerDetailPage>";    // redirect when all is done
            window.location = url;
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your `client.create` should return a deferred object as he is the only one method that is responsible for creating a contact and he is the only one who can resolve it:

```
toolkit.Client.prototype.create = function(fields, callback, errorHandler) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    // async call to database 

    //resolve def when the result is ready
    //def.resolve or def.refect();

    return def;
}
```

`createContact` must also return the result:

```
function createContact(fields) {      // Create 1 new contact
    var client = new toolkit.Client();
    return client.create(<fields>, callback, errorHandler);
}
```

and after that you can do:

```
function createContacts() {       // Create 1 or more new contacts
    var actions = [];
    $('.row').each(function() {
        // prep fields
        actions.push(createContact(fields));
    }

    return actions;
}

function saveAll() {
    createCustomer();
    $.when.apply($, createContacts()).done(function(){
        var url = "<newCustomerDetailPage>";    // redirect when all is done
        window.location = url;
    });
}
```